Flutter Web Safari on iOS Simulator keyboard pops again on tap Done button
I have a textfield with number type and for testing I'm running app on responsive web version with iOS simulator. As below in GIF keyboard appears again on tap done. How can i fix this?
Code:
    SizedBox(
      width: context.isDesktop ? 300 : (context.width - 40),
      height: 50,
      child: TextField(
        controller: _textController,
        autocorrect: false,
        enableSuggestions: false,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        style: DesignFont.regular(20),
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          hintText: Localized.enterPinCode,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2)),
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: StyleColor.border),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )



Try to take onSubmitted to your TextField with handle keyboard 'Done' button action TextInputAction.done and give unfocus to FocusScope.
Added code related to the same. Hope it helps

Handle done action on keyboard for unfocus
void handleAction(TextInputAction action) {
    if (action == TextInputAction.done) {
      // Handle the "Done" action
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
  }
}

on TextField add
onSubmitted: (value) => handleAction(TextInputAction.done)


tried but not working
